# Is it possible to extract the Maven Version within a VSTS Build Plan or Release

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Currently using VSTS to build Spring Boot applications with Maven. Trying to figure out how to use/get the Maven Version within the build and release process.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you need something more than 'mvn -v'?

Comment: Or if you're actually in the build and you need it there, then `${maven.version}`.

Comment: @PaulHicks I can't find anywhere that ${maven.version} is a valid build or release variable within VSTS.

Comment: No, not in VSTS. In your pom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script that will get the version of maven (given the path) and store the version number in a variable that other tasks can use later in the build.

```
$mvn = "$Env:M2_HOME\bin\mvn.bat"
$version = (& $mvn -v | select-string -pattern '(Apache\sMaven\s)([^\s]*)').Matches.Groups[2].Value
Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=MavenVersion;]$version")
```

The name of the environment variable is MavenVersion as you can see in the last line. You can use this variable like you would any other environment variable in subsequent scripts or build processes.

I tested this script on the Hosted Build machine, so the path to Maven was under M2_HOME and ended with .bat (Maven 2). You may want to add more code to figure out the path to Maven more generically.

Answer (score 0):

And here is the script in python:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('pom.xml')

#print 'BuildNumber: ', BuildNumber

value =tree.find('./{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}version')
print 'Found value:', value.text

print "##vso[task.setvariable variable=POM_VERSION;]", value.text
```

This is running fine on linux based build agents. The output variable is `POM_VERSION`.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is like so :

```
mvn -v | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

The above snippet will print : `3.8.5` for example